# Stored Procedure Output Returning Null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I was asked to write a stored procedure that would create (INSERT) a survey response, with the SurveyGUID as an input and the SurveyResponseGUID as an output. But when I set my output after inserting the response, I return null.

Is there  a way to set the OUT param when I perform the INSERT?

The insert works, and the query where I set my output param works on its own when I remove the INTO part.  I've tried to find solutions but I haven't been lucky. I am new to MySQL so any help or tips would be appreciated.

```
USE db;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spCreateSurveyResponse;
DELIMITER ??

CREATE PROCEDURE spCreateSurveyResponse(
    IN surveyGUID varchar(36),
    OUT responseGUID varchar(36))
BEGIN 
    SET @surveyId = ( SELECT SurveyId FROM db.Survey WHERE SurveyGuid = surveyGUID);

    INSERT INTO SurveyResponse (SurveyId, ResponseGuid) VALUES (@surveyId, UUID());

    SELECT 
        ResponseGuid INTO responseGUID
        FROM 
            db.SurveyResponse 
        WHERE 
            SurveyDetailId = last_insert_id();

END ??


DELIMITER ;

-- CALL spCreateSurveyResponse('Survey GUID here', @responseGUID);
-- SELECT @responseGUID;
```

SELECT @responseGUID always returns Null when I call the procedure from another SQL file.

Comment: Make sure you properly distinguish between table columns and input parameter as MySQL supports case insensitivity.

Comment: You solved it! I changed the param names to param_surveyGUID and param_responseGUID and voila! You rock.

Answer (score 1):

Per Jitendra's comment I tried changing the parameter's names, and it worked!

```
USE db;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS spCreateSurveyResponse;
DELIMITER ??

CREATE PROCEDURE spCreateSurveyResponse(
    IN param_surveyGUID varchar(36),
    OUT param_responseGUID varchar(36))
BEGIN 
    SET @surveyId = ( SELECT SurveyId FROM db.Survey WHERE SurveyGuid = param_surveyGUID);

    INSERT INTO SurveyResponse (SurveyId, ResponseGuid) VALUES (@surveyId, UUID());

    SELECT 
        ResponseGuid INTO param_responseGUID
        FROM 
            db.SurveyResponse 
        WHERE 
            SurveyDetailId = last_insert_id();

END ??
```